# SSRS Report - How to merge cells into a single cell of 2 different column grouping columns?

Tags: reporting-services

Let's say, I have 2 column groups in SSRS report. In 1st column group, there are 2 columns and in 2nd column group, there are 2 columns as well. Now, I want to merge all 4 columns together and bind it with one of the columns present in dataset. I don't understand how to merge columns of 2 different adjacent column groups. Please explain.

I have tried using advanced mode in column group pane but couldn't find anything. Please suggest